# show a button through alertview button in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a alertview it appears every time when the app is launched. I want to show a button on a viewcontroller when I clicked  show button of alertview when I clicked on cancel then button then this button will not show. I am using this code to do this.

```
- (void )alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{

    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    controller.button.hidden= NO;
}
```

and in viewcontroller I create the outlet of button. and done the below code in view did load of view controller  but I am unable to show the
 button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: both action in the same view controller

Comment: Don't alloc init the view.

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad Why not?

Comment: @Tim007 If you are in current view then what is the need of alloc ?

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad Ah i see, alloc init to hide button lol : D

Comment: No Sir @anbu-karthik, there is only one view controller. I am using the alertview in app delegate.m and the view did load is in view controller. and I want to show the button in view controller if i pressed on alertview button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. Use `UIAlertController` with a preferredStyle of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Init hide button
    self.button.hidden = YES;
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //Show button
        self.button.hidden = NO;
    }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //Hide button
        self.button.hidden = YES;
    }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Your current code can be like that:

delegate.m

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    //Show button
    controller.button.hidden = NO;
}];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    //Hide button
    controller.button.hidden = YES;
}];
[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //self.button.hidden = NO; remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

only add this line in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.button.hidden = NO;
```

you have to replace the code in viewdid load...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
```

TO

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nibName];
```

Check whether it works!!

Answer (score 1):

When you create the UIAlertView set ViewController (the same instance that will be your rootViewController) to it's delegate and then in the ViewController implement the

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

delegate method. In there you can use self.button